# FLVPlayback component and a playpause button - autohide?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using a FLvPlayBack component and I have the skin setting set to none. I've dragged a PlayPauseButton from my library to my stage in a movieclip. The button pauses and plays the video, but now what i want to do is mimic the "autohide" feature in a normal skin.

Does anyone know how i might accomplish this?

Comment: define "autohide" feature in a normal skin

Comment: Autohide as in when i mouseover the video, the play button appears. When i mouseoff of the video the button disappears.  I need to have it so the button is not visible all of the time. And i just want to show a playbutton, not a skin that goes the whole width of the video.  I would like to just a builtin skin, but i was not exactly sure how to modify it so it wouldn't take up the whole width of the FLvPlayBack component when it was on the stage.  I need to not adjust the width of the video and i am trying to move it over to the left a bit on my stage, there is whitespace in the video.

Comment: What i am trying now is a 2 event script. I made a button that acts as a hotspot. when you mouseover the hotspot, the play button appears. When you mouseoff off the hotspot it disappears. The only problem i have now is when i try to click the playpausebutton it flickers like crazy (probably because it can't tell if i am mouseon or mouseoff of the hotspot because the hotspot overlaps the button. any suggestions how to tell that when i am over the playpausebutton i was the button to remain visible...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give FLVPlayback an instance name.
2. Add EventListeners mouseOver and mouseOut to the instance of FLVPlayback.
3. Convert the buttons into a movieClip and give the movieClip an instance name.
4. In Event Listener:
   function for mouseOver: alpha = 1, 
   function for mouseOut : alpha = 0;

   For replication of the effect , use the tween class with alpha parameter and 0.0seconds duration.

> ```
> new Tween(movieClip1,"alpha",None.easeOut,1,0,0.5,true);
> ```

in mouseOut.

> ```
> new Tween(movieClip1,"alpha",None.easeOut,0,1,0.5,true);
> ```

in mouseOver.

**NOTE:**
For tween two classes to be imported

> import fl.transitions.Tween;
>   import fl.transitions.easing.*;

Comment: Thanks for your help, i might add that tweening to it to make it extra slick.

Answer (score 1):

Take the hotspot out. Add an eventlistener to the flvplayback component for mouseover and mouseout. on mouse over make the button visible. on mouseout hide the button.


If you want me to be more specific you will need to post some of your code.


[EDIT]
Add a movieClip Wrapper around the FLVPlayback component and add the mouse events to the wrapper.
FLVPlayback component apparently does not respond to mouse events if there is no video displayed and no controls being displayed.

Comment: I will try that again, but i did try adding the eventListener to the FLVPlayback component but it didnt work. I'l try it again thogh and report back. Thanks very much for the assist.

Comment: WelcomeVideo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fl_MouseOverHandler);
    
    function fl_MouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
     // Start your custom code
     // This example code displays the words "Moused over" in the Output panel.
     trace("Moused over");
     btnPlayPause.visible = true;
     // End your custom code
    }
    
    WelcomeVideo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fl_MouseOutHandler);
    
    function fl_MouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
     trace("Moused out");
     btnPlayPause.visible = false;
    }

Comment: That is my code I have and when i put my mouseover the video, nothing happens. I've verified that the video component has the name WelcomeVideo. Does the video have to be in a button or can it just on the stage?

Comment: Code works for me. You need to have a video playing. One work around wrap it in a movieclip or a sprite and add the mouse events to that don't forget to add a background image so the mouse has something to interact with. apparently the FVLPlayback component has no height without the video playing and controls not showing.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I had to put the FLVPlayBack component and the playpausebutton in a movieclip. I am then able to add eventlistener on the mouseover / mouseout states so now my play buttons appears and disappears correctly.  I can't post the answer, but if you want to post the correct answer below, i'll give you points since you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I added an edit to this answer so you can just accept the is one.